# The parser didn't comsume all tokens,Is it a bug?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

env: antlr 4.7.1

the grammer is:

```
grammar Whilelang;
program : seqStatement;
seqStatement: statement (';' statement)* ;
statement: ID ':=' expression                          # attrib
     | 'print' Text                                # print
     | '{' seqStatement '}'                        # block
     ;
expression: INT                                        # int
      | ID                                         # id
      | expression ('+'|'-') expression            # binOp
      | '(' expression ')'                         # expParen
      ;
bool: ('true'|'false')                                 # boolean
    | expression '=' expression                        # relOp
    | expression '<=' expression                       # relOp
    | 'not' bool                                       # not
    | bool 'and' bool                                  # and
    | '(' bool ')'                                     # boolParen
;
INT: ('0'..'9')+ ;
ID: ('a'..'z')+;
Text: '"' .*? '"';
Space: [ \t\n\r] -> skip;
```

The input language code are:

```
a := 1
b := 2
```

According to the grammar, Antlr4 should output a error --" expect ';' at line 1 " for the above input language code. But in fact. no error ouputted, It seems the grammar accept only partial input, and didn't consume all input tokens.
Is it a bug of antlr4?

```
$ grun Whilelang program -trace
a := 1
b := 2
^d
enter   program, LT(1)=a
enter   seqStatement, LT(1)=a
enter   statement, LT(1)=a
consume [@0,0:0='a',<17>,1:0] rule statement
consume [@1,2:3=':=',<2>,1:2] rule statement
enter   expression, LT(1)=1
consume [@2,5:5='1',<16>,1:5] rule expression
exit    expression, LT(1)=b
exit    statement, LT(1)=b
exit    seqStatement, LT(1)=b
exit    program, LT(1)=b
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. ANTLR is doing exactly what it was asked to do.

Given the rules

```
program : seqStatement;
seqStatement: statement (';' statement)* ;
```

the `program` rule is then entirely complete when at least one `statement` has been matched. Since the parser cannot validly match another `statement` -- optional per the grammar-- it stops.

Changing to

```
program : seqStatement EOF;
```

requires the `program` rule to match `statements` until it can also match an `EOF` token (the lexer automatically adds an `EOF` at the end of the source text). This likely the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: It works! thank you very much